# How to configure one to many relationship along with inheritance in entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working on entity framework code first pattern. I have one scenario where i have following entities,

```
public class Toy
{
public int ID {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

for the above entity, all model building configuration has been done and table was created fine.

We have another entity,

```
public class Kid
{
public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

For this entity also, all model building configuration has been done and table was craeted fine in database.

Now i need to maintain/configure, one -many relationship between kid and toys i.e. one kid can have multiple toys

so i have create one custom class which will inherit Kid class,

```
public class KidToy : Kid
{
public virtual List<Toy> Toys{get; set;}
}
```

> Note: I can't add List Toys property directly in Kid class, i am
>   getting circular refernce error.

```
builder.Entity<Kid>().Map<KidToy>(m => {

            });

            builder.Entity<KidToy>().HasMany(b => b.Toys).WithMany().Map(b =>
            {
                b.MapLeftKey(KidId");
                b.MapRightKey("ToyId");
                b.ToTable("kidToyMap");
            });
```

I dont need table creation for the custom model class (KidToy) and i need to configure one-many relationship. Could you please guide me.

Comment: That looks more like a many to many configuration. Why not just add the Toys collection inside kid? http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx Not sure on your need for inheritance. KidToy does not appear to be a kind of kid https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27db6csx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
public class Toy
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int KidID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("KidID")]
    [InverseProperty("Toys")]
    public virtual Kid Kid { get; set; }
}

public class Kid
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Kid")]
    public virtual ICollection<Toy> Toys { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in reverse where the parent has a list of items of a derived type and the child entity has a property to its parent as the base type?